# ESP32-cam with servo control won't work. Arduino IDE

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, servo

I've an ESP32-cam and want to controll a servo. My code compiled without error but doesn't work.
There are two files involved, a .ino and a .cpp. The .ino seems to work right because the servo contributes to his start position 90° at startup but When i want to turn it right or left, nothing happens. This part is controlled in the .cpp and i've spend a lot of time to figure out what went wrong here without success. Any help is highly appreciated.

.ino

```
    #include "esp_camera.h"
    #include <WiFiMulti.h>
    #include <Servo.h>

    Servo myservo;

    WiFiMulti wifiMulti;
    int ledPin = 4;

    #define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER

    #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
    #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
    #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
    #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
    #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

    #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
    #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
    #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
    #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
    #define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
    #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
    #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
    #define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
    #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
    #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
    #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

    // GPIO Setting
    int servoPin  =  2;
    int posDegrees = 90;                              //servo initial position 90°
    int posDegreesStep = 30;

    extern String WiFiAddr ="";

    void startCameraServer();

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
      Serial.println();
      
      myservo.attach(servoPin, 2, 0, 180);            //(pin, channel, min, max) degrees
      myservo.write(posDegrees); 

      pinMode(servoPin , OUTPUT );
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      
      camera_config_t config;
      config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
      config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
      config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
      config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
      config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
      //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
      if(psramFound()){
        config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SXGA;
        config.jpeg_quality = 10;
        config.fb_count = 2;
      } else {
        config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
        config.jpeg_quality = 12;
        config.fb_count = 1;
      }

      // camera init
      esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
      if (err != ESP_OK) {
        Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
        return;
      }

      //drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
      sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
      s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_CIF);

      wifiMulti.addAP("ssid_from_AP_1", "your_password_for_AP_1");
      wifiMulti.addAP("ssid_from_AP_3", "your_password_for_AP_2");
      //wifiMulti.addAP("ssid_from_AP_3", "your_password_for_AP_3");

      Serial.println("Connecting Wifi...");
      if (wifiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("WiFi connected");
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        Serial.print("SSID:       ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
      }

      startCameraServer();

      Serial.print("Camera Ready!");
      Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
      WiFiAddr = WiFi.localIP().toString();
      Serial.println("' to connect");
    }

    void wifireconnect() {

      if (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("WiFi not connected!");
        delay(500);
        WiFi.disconnect();
        Serial.println("\nReboot");
        ESP.restart();
      }
    }

    void loop() {
     
       wifireconnect();
    }
```

.cpp

```
    #include "esp_http_server.h"
    #include "esp_timer.h"
    #include "esp_camera.h"
    #include "img_converters.h"
    #include "camera_index.h"
    #include "Arduino.h"
    #include "Servo.h"

    extern int servoPin;
    extern int posDegrees;
    extern int posDegreesStep;

    extern String WiFiAddr;

    typedef struct {
      size_t size;
      size_t index;
      size_t count;
      int sum;
      int * values;
    } ra_filter_t;

    typedef struct {
      httpd_req_t *req;
      size_t len;
    } jpg_chunking_t;

    #define PART_BOUNDARY "123456789000000000000987654321"
    static const char* _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" PART_BOUNDARY;
    static const char* _STREAM_BOUNDARY = "\r\n--" PART_BOUNDARY "\r\n";
    static const char* _STREAM_PART = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: %u\r\n\r\n";

    static ra_filter_t ra_filter;
    httpd_handle_t stream_httpd = NULL;
    httpd_handle_t camera_httpd = NULL;

    static ra_filter_t * ra_filter_init(ra_filter_t * filter, size_t sample_size) {
      memset(filter, 0, sizeof(ra_filter_t));

      filter->values = (int *)malloc(sample_size * sizeof(int));
      if (!filter->values) {
        return NULL;
      }
      memset(filter->values, 0, sample_size * sizeof(int));

      filter->size = sample_size;
      return filter;
    }

    static int ra_filter_run(ra_filter_t * filter, int value) {
      if (!filter->values) {
        return value;
      }
      filter->sum -= filter->values[filter->index];
      filter->values[filter->index] = value;
      filter->sum += filter->values[filter->index];
      filter->index++;
      filter->index = filter->index % filter->size;
      if (filter->count < filter->size) {
        filter->count++;
      }
      return filter->sum / filter->count;
    }

    static size_t jpg_encode_stream(void * arg, size_t index, const void* data, size_t len) {
      jpg_chunking_t *j = (jpg_chunking_t *)arg;
      if (!index) {
        j->len = 0;
      }
      if (httpd_resp_send_chunk(j->req, (const char *)data, len) != ESP_OK) {
        return 0;
      }
      j->len += len;
      return len;
    }

    static esp_err_t capture_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
      camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
      esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
      int64_t fr_start = esp_timer_get_time();

      fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
      if (!fb) {
        Serial.printf("Camera capture failed");
        httpd_resp_send_500(req);
        return ESP_FAIL;
      }

      httpd_resp_set_type(req, "image/jpeg");
      httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=capture.jpg");

      size_t fb_len = 0;
      if (fb->format == PIXFORMAT_JPEG) {
        fb_len = fb->len;
        res = httpd_resp_send(req, (const char *)fb->buf, fb->len);
      } else {
        jpg_chunking_t jchunk = {req, 0};
        res = frame2jpg_cb(fb, 80, jpg_encode_stream, &jchunk) ? ESP_OK : ESP_FAIL;
        httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, NULL, 0);
        fb_len = jchunk.len;
      }
      esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
      int64_t fr_end = esp_timer_get_time();
      Serial.printf("JPG: %uB %ums", (uint32_t)(fb_len), (uint32_t)((fr_end - fr_start) / 1000));
      return res;
    }

    static esp_err_t stream_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
      camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
      esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
      size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
      uint8_t * _jpg_buf = NULL;
      char * part_buf[64];

      static int64_t last_frame = 0;
      if (!last_frame) {
        last_frame = esp_timer_get_time();
      }

      res = httpd_resp_set_type(req, _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE);
      if (res != ESP_OK) {
        return res;
      }

      while (true) {
        fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
        if (!fb) {
          Serial.printf("Camera capture failed");
          res = ESP_FAIL;
        } else {
          if (fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG) {
            bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
            esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
            fb = NULL;
            if (!jpeg_converted) {
              Serial.printf("JPEG compression failed");
              res = ESP_FAIL;
            }
          } else {
            _jpg_buf_len = fb->len;
            _jpg_buf = fb->buf;
          }
        }
        if (res == ESP_OK) {
          size_t hlen = snprintf((char *)part_buf, 64, _STREAM_PART, _jpg_buf_len);
          res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)part_buf, hlen);
        }
        if (res == ESP_OK) {
          res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)_jpg_buf, _jpg_buf_len);
        }
        if (res == ESP_OK) {
          res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, _STREAM_BOUNDARY, strlen(_STREAM_BOUNDARY));
        }
        if (fb) {
          esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
          fb = NULL;
          _jpg_buf = NULL;
        } else if (_jpg_buf) {
          free(_jpg_buf);
          _jpg_buf = NULL;
        }
        if (res != ESP_OK) {
          break;
        }
        int64_t fr_end = esp_timer_get_time();

        int64_t frame_time = fr_end - last_frame;
        last_frame = fr_end;
        frame_time /= 1000;
        uint32_t avg_frame_time = ra_filter_run(&ra_filter, frame_time);
        //Serial.printf("MJPG: %uB %ums (%.1ffps), AVG: %ums (%.1ffps)"
        //    ,(uint32_t)(_jpg_buf_len),
        //    (uint32_t)frame_time, 1000.0 / (uint32_t)frame_time,
        //    avg_frame_time, 1000.0 / avg_frame_time
        //);
      }

      last_frame = 0;
      return res;
    }

    static esp_err_t cmd_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
      char*  buf;
      size_t buf_len;
      char variable[32] = {0,};
      char value[32] = {0,};

      buf_len = httpd_req_get_url_query_len(req) + 1;
      if (buf_len > 1) {
        buf = (char*)malloc(buf_len);
        if (!buf) {
          httpd_resp_send_500(req);
          return ESP_FAIL;
        }
        if (httpd_req_get_url_query_str(req, buf, buf_len) == ESP_OK) {
          if (httpd_query_key_value(buf, "var", variable, sizeof(variable)) == ESP_OK &&
              httpd_query_key_value(buf, "val", value, sizeof(value)) == ESP_OK) {
          } else {
            free(buf);
            httpd_resp_send_404(req);
            return ESP_FAIL;
          }
        } else {
          free(buf);
          httpd_resp_send_404(req);
          return ESP_FAIL;
        }
        free(buf);
      } else {
        httpd_resp_send_404(req);
        return ESP_FAIL;
      }

      int val = atoi(value);
      sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
      int res = 0;

      if (!strcmp(variable, "framesize")) {
        if (s->pixformat == PIXFORMAT_JPEG) res = s->set_framesize(s, (framesize_t)val);
      }
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "quality")) res = s->set_quality(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "contrast")) res = s->set_contrast(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "brightness")) res = s->set_brightness(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "saturation")) res = s->set_saturation(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "gainceiling")) res = s->set_gainceiling(s, (gainceiling_t)val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "colorbar")) res = s->set_colorbar(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "awb")) res = s->set_whitebal(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "agc")) res = s->set_gain_ctrl(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "aec")) res = s->set_exposure_ctrl(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "hmirror")) res = s->set_hmirror(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "vflip")) res = s->set_vflip(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "awb_gain")) res = s->set_awb_gain(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "agc_gain")) res = s->set_agc_gain(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "aec_value")) res = s->set_aec_value(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "aec2")) res = s->set_aec2(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "dcw")) res = s->set_dcw(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "bpc")) res = s->set_bpc(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "wpc")) res = s->set_wpc(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "raw_gma")) res = s->set_raw_gma(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "lenc")) res = s->set_lenc(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "special_effect")) res = s->set_special_effect(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "wb_mode")) res = s->set_wb_mode(s, val);
      else if (!strcmp(variable, "ae_level")) res = s->set_ae_level(s, val);
      else {
        res = -1;
      }

      if (res) {
        return httpd_resp_send_500(req);
      }

      httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      return httpd_resp_send(req, NULL, 0);
    }

    static esp_err_t status_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
      static char json_response[1024];

      sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
      char * p = json_response;
      *p++ = '{';

      p += sprintf(p, "\"framesize\":%u,", s->status.framesize);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"quality\":%u,", s->status.quality);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"brightness\":%d,", s->status.brightness);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"contrast\":%d,", s->status.contrast);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"saturation\":%d,", s->status.saturation);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"special_effect\":%u,", s->status.special_effect);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"wb_mode\":%u,", s->status.wb_mode);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"awb\":%u,", s->status.awb);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"awb_gain\":%u,", s->status.awb_gain);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"aec\":%u,", s->status.aec);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"aec2\":%u,", s->status.aec2);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"ae_level\":%d,", s->status.ae_level);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"aec_value\":%u,", s->status.aec_value);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"agc\":%u,", s->status.agc);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"agc_gain\":%u,", s->status.agc_gain);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"gainceiling\":%u,", s->status.gainceiling);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"bpc\":%u,", s->status.bpc);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"wpc\":%u,", s->status.wpc);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"raw_gma\":%u,", s->status.raw_gma);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"lenc\":%u,", s->status.lenc);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"hmirror\":%u,", s->status.hmirror);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"dcw\":%u,", s->status.dcw);
      p += sprintf(p, "\"colorbar\":%u", s->status.colorbar);
      *p++ = '}';
      *p++ = 0;
      httpd_resp_set_type(req, "application/json");
      httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      return httpd_resp_send(req, json_response, strlen(json_response));
    }

    static esp_err_t index_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
      httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
      String page = "";
      page += "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\">\n";
      page += "<p><h2></h2></p><br/><br/><br/>";
      page += "<script>var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();</script>";
      page += "<script>function getsend(arg) { xhttp.open('GET', arg +'?' + new Date().getTime(), true); xhttp.send() } </script>";
      //page += "<p align=center><IMG SRC='http://" + WiFiAddr + ":81/stream' style='width:280px;'></p><br/><br/>";
      page += "<p align=center><IMG SRC='http://" + WiFiAddr + ":81/stream' style='width:600px; transform:rotate(0deg);'></p><br/>";

      //page += "<p align=center> <button style=width:90px;height:80px onmousedown=getsend('go') onmouseup=getsend('stop') ontouchstart=getsend('go') ontouchend=getsend('stop') ></button> </p>";
      //page += "<p align=center>";
      //page += "<button style=width:90px;height:80px onmousedown=getsend('left') onmouseup=getsend('stop') ontouchstart=getsend('left') ontouchend=getsend('stop')></button>&nbsp;";
      //page += "<button style=width:90px;height:80px onmousedown=getsend('stop') onmouseup=getsend('stop')></button>&nbsp;";
      //page += "<button style=width:90px;height:80px onmousedown=getsend('right') onmouseup=getsend('stop') ontouchstart=getsend('right') ontouchend=getsend('stop')></button>";
      //page += "</p>";

      //page += "<p align=center><button style=width:90px;height:80px onmousedown=getsend('back') onmouseup=getsend('stop') ontouchstart=getsend('back') ontouchend=getsend('stop') ></button></p>";

      page += "<p align=center><br/><br/>";
      page += "<button style=width:120px;height:40px;background:#768d87 onmousedown=getsend('links')>links</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      page += "<button style=width:150px;height:40px;background:#91b8b3 onmousedown=getsend('reboot')>ESP Restart</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      page += "<button style=width:120px;height:40px;background:#768d87 onmousedown=getsend('rechts')>rechts</button>";
      page += "</p>";

      return httpd_resp_send(req, &page[0], strlen(&page[0]));
    }

    static esp_err_t reboot_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.println("rebooting");
      delay(2000);
      ESP.restart();
      httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
      return httpd_resp_send(req, "OK", 2);
    }

    static esp_err_t links_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {

      Servo myservo;

      if (posDegrees >= 0 && posDegrees <= 180) {
        posDegrees = posDegrees + posDegreesStep;
      }
      if (posDegrees > 180) {
        posDegrees = 180;
      }
      else {
        myservo.write(posDegrees);                    // move the servo to calculated angle
        Serial.print("Moved to: ");
        Serial.print(posDegrees);                     // print the angle
        Serial.println(" degree");
      }
      httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
      return httpd_resp_send(req, "OK", 2);
      }
      static esp_err_t rechts_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {

      Servo myservo;

      if (posDegrees > 0 && posDegrees <= 180) {
        posDegrees = posDegrees - posDegreesStep;
      }
      if (posDegrees < 0) {
        posDegrees = 0;
      } else {
        myservo.write(posDegrees);                    // move the servo to calculated angle
        Serial.print("Moved to: ");
        Serial.print(posDegrees);                     // print the angle
        Serial.println(" degree");
      }

      httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
      return httpd_resp_send(req, "OK", 2);
    }

    void startCameraServer() {
      httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();

      httpd_uri_t reboot_uri = {
        .uri       = "/reboot",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = reboot_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      httpd_uri_t links_uri = {
        .uri       = "/links",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = links_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      httpd_uri_t rechts_uri = {
        .uri       = "/rechts",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = rechts_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      httpd_uri_t index_uri = {
        .uri       = "/",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = index_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      httpd_uri_t status_uri = {
        .uri       = "/status",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = status_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      httpd_uri_t cmd_uri = {
        .uri       = "/control",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = cmd_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      httpd_uri_t capture_uri = {
        .uri       = "/capture",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = capture_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      httpd_uri_t stream_uri = {
        .uri       = "/stream",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = stream_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
      };

      ra_filter_init(&ra_filter, 20);
      Serial.printf("Starting web server on port: '%d'", config.server_port);
      if (httpd_start(&camera_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
        httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &index_uri);
        httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &reboot_uri);
        httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &links_uri);
        httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &rechts_uri);
      } else {
        Serial.printf("Starting web server failed");
      }

      config.server_port += 1;
      config.ctrl_port += 1;
      Serial.printf("Starting stream server on port: '%d'", config.server_port);
      if (httpd_start(&stream_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
        httpd_register_uri_handler(stream_httpd, &stream_uri);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It's probably because the timers for the camera are interfering with the servo timers. You have to use this library, [ServoESP32](https://github.com/RoboticsBrno/ServoESP32), and attach your servo like this:

```
Servo remote; 
remote.attach(16, 2);
```

All this does is attach your servo to channel 2 given that channels 0 and 1 are being used by the CAM. I tried this and it fixed the problem instantly.

Comment: I think that's what i do.                                                                                   myservo.attach(servoPin, 2, 0, 180);            //(pin, channel, min, max) degrees                    I tried the differend ServoESP32 library, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution has suddenly stopped working for me as well.